# Anaconda : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

After installing `TensorFlow` in `Anaconda`, I tried to test it :

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

In `Jupyter`, I get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13080/3793406994.py in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

[image]

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal, then switch to your env directory and run:

```
conda activate virtual_env_name
```

now try again

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall tensorflow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

or

```
conda install tensorflow
```